# def_context_data for ImageField

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I need to show on main page my new application for showing 2 images. I have to assign it only to the view of the main page for use in my 'base.html'.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class MainPageImages(models.Model):
    left_img = models.ImageField(_('Left image'), upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d')
    right_img = models.ImageField(_('Right image'), upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d')
```

**views.py**:

```
class IndexView(AllAdsViewMixin, ListView):
model = UserContent
template_name = 'user_content/list.html'
context_object_name = 'object'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last all five published contents"""
    return UserContent.objects.filter(state='1').order_by('-published')[:5]

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    comment_initial_data = {
        'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).id
    }

    reply_initial_data = {
        'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Comment).id
    }

    comment_form = CommentForm(initial=comment_initial_data)
    reply_form = CommentForm(initial=reply_initial_data)
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comment_form'] = comment_form
    context['reply_form'] = reply_form

    return context

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content_type_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        object_id_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type_id)
        print(object_id_data)
        print(content_data)

    else:
        print(comment_form.errors)

    new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
        user=request.user,
        content_type=content_type,
        object_id=object_id_data,
        content=content_data,
    )

    return self.get(request, **kwargs)
```

Can you help me? I need edit that function and add my new app for use in templates.

All the best,
Dinson

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is very unclear, I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry. My English is so bad. Just I need to define my MainPageImages app in views.py in get_context_data so that I can use it in templates.

Comment: I don't think your English is the problem, I just can't see what your question is. What is stopping you doing what you want? And where is the rest of that view?

Comment: I edited my code with views.py. Just I don't know how can I use this app for view in homepage.

Comment: But what do you mean, "use this app for the homepage"? You can set the URL to be whatever you want.

Comment: Just my employer was talking about pushing the fields from my model only for the main page view.